# how to pass dynamic variables in json

Tags: php, json

```
function createOrder($entityid, $customerid, $dateorder, $warehouse, $price, $qty) {

    $json = '{"orderNo":"$entityid",'
            . '"customerCode": $customerid,'
            . '"dateOrdered": "08-07-2015",'
            . '"warehouseId" : 103,'
            . '"orderLineList":'
            . '['
            . '"productId": 1000002,'
            . '"qty": 6,'
         . '"price": 10]}';

$data = json_encode($json);
    print($data);
```

getting error msg

```
responseCode":500,"detailedMessage":null,"record":null,"recordNo":null,"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass value of varibles in json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290335/how-to-pass-value-of-varibles-in-json)

Comment: $json itself it is a json string, then why are you encoding it again?

Answer (score 0):

The json_encode function takes as parameter an array, not a string that looks like json. Here is what the documentation says

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

In your case, you should have

```
$arr = array ( 
"orderNo" => $entityid,
"dateOrdered" => "08-07-2015"
);
$jsonArr = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you are building a JSON string and then trying to encode it. Build an array and then encode it to get a json string.

```
$arrayToJson = array(
    "orderNo"=>$entityid,
    "customerCode" => $customerid,
    "dateOrdered" => "08-07-2015",
    "warehouseId" => 103,
    "orderLineList" => array(
        "productid" => 1000002,
        "qty" => 6
        "price" => 10
    ),
);
$json = json_encode($arrayToJson);
print($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a `JSON` at your own make an `array` and use `json_encode` function instead as

```
function createOrder($entityid, $customerid, $dateorder, $warehouse, $price, $qty) {

    $array = array("orderNo" => $entityid, "customerCode" => $customerid, "dateOrdered" => "08-07-2015", "warehouseId" => 103, "orderLineList" => array("productId" => 1000002, "qty" => 6, "price" => 10));

    $data = json_encode($array);
    print($data);
}
```

And if you have created at it your own then remove that variable `$data = json_encode($json);` and `print($json)`